# How to connect to Java Server Cloud9

Tags: java, networking, server

I've looked at the documentation and tried many things, but I can't seem to figure out how to connect to a Java Server running on Cloud9 from anywhere else. The Java Server/Client is using DatagramSockets and DatagramPackets to send and receive data. I've tried the eth0 IP, and many alias names I thought would work, but no avail...